# Why is the log statement in Spring WebClient subscribe() block not invoked?

Tags: spring, kotlin, webclient

I am playing around with the spring webclient to send emails via an api. The mails get send, however I am trying to do this without blocking and I want to log the successful response (or error). As I understood it so far, I could do this in the subscribe block. However, I do not manage to get the logging (or anything else) within the subscribe block to work.

MailClient.kt

```
fun sendMail(mail: Mail): Mono<String> {
        return getWebClient()
        .post()
        .uri("uri")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue(..)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
        //.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    }
```

Service function which uses MailClient:

```
       logger.info("Sending mail due to failure with id = ${failure.id}, error: $errorMessage")
        mailClient.sendMail(
            Mail(..)
        )
            .subscribe(
                { response -> logger.info("success: $response") },
                { error -> logger.error("error: $error") })
```

Comment: Are you saying when the email is successfully sent, There is no Log for the confirmation? also the same as on Error?

Comment: Yes, the mail is actually sent, however I do not see the logs defined in the subsribe block. The upper logstatement ("Sending mail due to failure...") works

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but give it a try @christian ..... .subscribe((response)=> {
                logger.info("success: $response")
            },error => logger.error("error: $error"))

Comment: Unfortunately that does not compile with kotlin

Comment: I am out of any idea good luck Christian